# Pass a list from a view to a controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this controller which creates a List where T is a class model called GamingEvents.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<GamingEvents> gamingEventsListings = await sg.GenerateGameEventsSchedule();

        ViewData["RangeStart"] = start;
        ViewData["RangeEnd"] = end;

        return View(gamingEventsListings);
    }
```

In my view I generate this table to display the data:

```
    @model List<GameManager.Models.GamingEvents>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GameId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GameName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayNames)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Now, I want to send all this data to another controller.  So I made this form:

```
<form asp-controller="Scheduling" asp-action="ScheduleBlock" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <button formaction="/Scheduling/ScheduleBlock/">Schedule Games</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So I need the method, GenerateGameEventsFromSchedule(), to accept the two data properties I pass to the view, ViewData["RangeStart"] and ViewData["RangeEnd"].

So I started to write the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateGameEventsFromSchedule(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {

        foreach (event in GamingEvents)
        {
            //...do this
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Obviously it's not finished.

My problem is, how would I pass the list of GamingEvents from my view above, to this new controller so that I can do additional processing on each item in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't. You query them again from the database.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what about passing two date values that I write out in the View like this: @ViewData["RangeStart"] and @ViewData["RangeEnd"]?  and then passing those to the new controller?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, those values are coming from *somewhere*. If they're hard-coded, then just use the same hard-coded values. If they're coming from the request, then you'd pass them along in the same way (i.e. just add them as params to the link you're creating on the page). If they were set by the user via a form submission, you can opt to pass them in the URL of the link or you could persist them in `Session`. It really depends on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well I created the first view so the game manager can look at the generated schedule, and then decide if they want to actually schedule it...if they do, then they click the link and it schedules what they see on screen.

Comment: If anything atomic is going to happen as a result of following the link, *it should not be a link*. You need to post a form. GET requests should be idempotent (i.e. you can call them 100s of times and the state of the system is exactly the same as when you started).

Comment: @ChrisPratt Ok, I ditched the idea of trying to pass in a whole list.  So I rephrased my question above.  I created two date properties that pass into the view.  I also created a new form. But I'm still unsure on how do I get the dates to send to the controller when I click the form button.  Thanks